# Dynamically create pages based on slug from API in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been learning about React Router have run into some issues while I was trying to implement a dynamic page creation based on the slugs that I receive from my fetch api call.

basically, I'm trying to redirect user to a new page after they click on a link - This new page will be a new component and I will make a new api call on this component with the slug as my search parameter.

However I'm struggling to dynamically change pages based on slugs.

Here is the component (BoxScore.js) in which I make the initial fetch and display data -

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const BoxScore = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);



  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `myfetchapihere.com`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setUsers(data);
        console.log(data);
        setPageNumber(pageNumber);
      });
  }, [pageNumber]);
     return (
         <> {users.map((user) => (
                <div
                  className="column"
                  key={user.id}
                  id={user.id}>
                  <div className="inner">
                    <div className="flex">
                      <h2 className="uk-text-small">
                     
         

 <Link to={user.slug} className="h2 link" id={user.slug}>
    {user.name}
    </Link>
    </div>

    </div></div>
        )}
</>);
```

In my App.js I have react router set up -

```
 <Routes>
      <Route path="boxscore/:slug" element={<BoxScore />}>
      <Route path=":slug" element={<OneScore />} />
    </Route>

   </Routes>
```

My OneScore component which isn't being rendered on the click of the link I set up in the Boxscore component -

```
import React from 'react'
import BoxScore from './Boxscore'
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import {useEffect} from 'react'

function OneScore() {

    const { slug } = useParams();
    
  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch post using the postSlug
    console.log({slug});
  }, [slug]);

  return (
    <div>
          Hiii
    </div>
  )
}

export default OneScore
```

EDIT - I have managed to make the linking work thanks to @DrewReese comments however, the only issue remains now is that after the url is changed to (ex- [www.a.com/boxscore/](http://www.a.com/boxscore/)) the 'OneScore' component is not rendered instead the same BoxScore remains just the url is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a raw anchor (`<a />`) tag use the [`Link`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) or [`NavLink`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) component. These link components work with the routing context being provided by the router. Using the anchor tag will reload the app, which very likely *isn't* what you want to occur.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

{users.map((user) => (
  <div
    className="column"
    key={user.id}
    id={user.id}
  >
    <div className="inner">
      <div className="flex">
        <Link to={user.slug} className="h2link" id={user.slug}>
          <h2 className="uk-text-small">{user.name}</h2>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)};
```

The routed component should use the [`useParams`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook to access the route's `slug` path param and an `useEffect` hook to rerun any logic that depends on this slug value.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { slug } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  // "make a new api call on this component with the slug as my search parameter"
}, [slug]);
```

Comment: Hey, I did try this earlier and while it works and my url changes to boxscore(slug) but the new component is not being rendered,The UI stays on the same 'Boxscore' component, I think I'm doing smth wrong in the <Routes> part but not sure exactly what that is

Comment: @KentrellJr I suppose it depends on that values being mapped from this `users` array. Could you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example? The main component rendering the mapped `users` array, the value of `users`, and both the `BoxScore` and `OneScore` components you are trying to link to?

Comment: Hey, I have attached the code for OneScore component in my post, the existing code in which I map over the users is a part of my BoxScore component, My only issues now is that when I click on the Link in the boxscore comp the url changes to something like (www.a.com/boxscore/myexampleslug) but the UI remains in BoxScore component instead of routing to the OneScore, As for the values of the users array - It is working fine as I'm able to fetch and render them in the BoxScore component

Comment: @KentrellJr The routes seem a little backwards, but provided the links and "slugs" are correct the links and routing should work just fine. What are the `user` values that you are mapping? What are the values of `user.slug` you are attempting to link to? Also, just as a hint moving forward, you'll likely find it easier to use more descriptive route param variable names, basically anything other than "slug" everywhere.

Comment: @KentrellJr Since `BoxScore` doesn't appear to use the "slug" it makes more sense to have these as your routes: `<Route path="boxscore" element={<BoxScore />}>` and `<Route path="/boxscore/:slug" element={<OneScore />} />` and ensure the links from `BoxScore` link correctly to `"/boxscore/:slug"` paths.

Comment: @KentrellJr When the URL is `"www.a.com/boxscore/myexampleslug"` this is the path you are rendering `BoxScore` component on, so it won't match and render the other route rendering the `OneScore` component.

Comment: Hey, I think I got it working now, the issue was in the Routes like you suggested, I was closing the `<Route path="boxscore" element={<BoxScore />}>` after `<Route path="/boxscore/:slug" element={<OneScore />} />`, Once I fixed that it does render a new page with the slug in url. Thank you so much for your patience and help and really appreciate the tip, I'll keep that in mind always!

Answer (score 0):

Look into useParams to get the slug from the url.
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Comment: I have had a look into that but I'm not sure how to even redirect a user to a new dynamic component on click of that <a>.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what do you mean by redirect to a new dynamic component? Do you mean change the browser url and load a new page that is dynamic based on the fetch from the slug url or do you mean load a new dynamic component on the same browser url?

Comment: Okay so what I mean is suppose my url is - www.a.com/boxscore on load but when a user clicks one of elements it redirects them to a new page - www.a.com/boxscore/<slug> - This new page should be a new component where I can fetch and render data for this specific slug through my api endpoint, I got the url part working now but my new component where I'm passing {slug} into useParams is not rendering and I stay on the same page.